# Proof that auto-correlation function of stationary series depends on constant, if we use linear prediction

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation

Consider question 1.10c of Shumway's book: 
https://www.stat.pitt.edu/stoffer/tsa4/tsa4.pdf

Below the actual statement (I just fixed the greek letter used for auto-correlation function, to be consistent with his own notation; and added a note about constant A):

1.10 Suppose we would like to predict a single stationary series $x_t$, with zero mean and auto-correlation function $\rho(h)$ at some time in future, say, $t + l$ for $l > 0$.

c) Show that if $x_{t+l} = Ax_{t}$ (for some scalar multiplier $A$), then $\rho(l) = 1$ if $A > 0$, and $\rho(l) = -1$ if $A < 0$.

My lame attempt to prove it:

The auto-correlation function is defined as:

$\rho(l) = \dfrac{\gamma(l)}{\gamma(0)}$

where the function $\gamma(h)$ is the auto-covariance function of the stationary time-series defined as:

$\gamma(l) = \gamma(l, 0) = \gamma(t+l, t) = cov(x_{t+l}, x_t)$

Now, by definition the covariance of those two random variables $x_{t+l}$ and $x_t$ is:

$cov(x_{t+l}, x_t) = E[(x_{t+l} - \mu_{t+l})(x_t - \mu_t)]$

Since we said $x_t$ has zero mean we can simplify to:

$E[(x_{t+l} - \mu_{t+l})(x_t - \mu_t)] = E[x_{t+l}\,x_t]$

Now, since we are saying that time $t+l$ is to be predicted with $Ax_t$, then we can rewrite as:

$E[x_{t+l}\,x_t] = E[A x_t\,x_t]$

By linear properties of the expected-value operation we can take the constant $A$ out:

$E[A\,x_t\,x_t] = A\,E[x_t\,x_t]$

and then we realize that $E[x_t\,x_t]$ is the (assumed finite) variance of the time-series itself, which per author notation can be written as $\gamma(0)$ ... at least for [weakly] stationary time-series:

$A\,E[x_t\,x_t] = A\,cov(x_t, x_t) = A\,var(x_t) = A\,\gamma(0)$

Putting everything together, we have that:

$\rho(l) = \dfrac{\gamma(l)}{\gamma(0)} = \dfrac{A\,\gamma(0)}{\gamma(0)} = A$

and above is clearly not what we want, we should be getting something like $sign(A)$. Where did I screw it up?

Thanks.

Edit1: Thanks to folks who provided comments. Following the advise I solved it using non-abbreviated definition of auto-correlation function $\rho(l)$ (left side of definition 1.9/equation (1.24) from the book at page 21). That is:

$\rho(l) = \dfrac{\gamma(t + l, t)}{\sqrt{\gamma(t+l, t+l)\,\gamma(t,t)}}$

where $\gamma(t,t)$ is still the auto-covariance function; though without using the abbreviation that applies to stationary series (which we should be able to use, but let us hold on that for a bit).

With definition above in mind, let us develop a couple of terms in numerator and denominator; leveraging the forecasting technique of $x_{t+l} = Ax_t$:

\begin{align}
\gamma(t+l, t) &= cov(x_{t+l}, x_t) \\
               &= cov(A\,x_t, x_t) \\
               &= A\,cov(x_t,x_t) \\
               &= A\, \gamma(t,t)
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\gamma(t+l, t+l) &= cov(x_{t+l}, x_{t+l}) \\
                 &= cov(A\,x_t, A\,x_t) \\
                 &= A^2\,cov(x_t, x_t) \\
                 &= A^2\,\gamma(t,t)
\end{align}

Replacing the two above in the definition for auto-correlation function $\rho(l)$ yields:

\begin{align}
\rho(l) 
&= \dfrac{\gamma(t + l, t)}{\sqrt{\gamma(t+l, t+l)\,\gamma(t,t)}} \\
&= \dfrac{A\, \gamma(t,t)}{\sqrt{A^2\,\gamma(t,t)\,\gamma(t,t)}} \\
&= \dfrac{A\, \gamma(t,t)}{\sqrt{A^2\,\gamma^2(t,t)}} \\
&= \dfrac{A\, \gamma(t,t)}{\left|A\,\gamma(t,t)\right|} \\
&= \dfrac{A\, \gamma(t,t)}{|A|\,|\gamma(t,t)|} \\
&= \dfrac{A\, \gamma(t,t)}{|A|\,\gamma(t,t)} \\
&= \dfrac{A}{|A|} \\
&= sign(A) \\
\end{align}

Which is what the exercise wanted. So the whole problem with my previous reasoning was using right side of definition 1.9/equation (1.24) from the book at page 21; which is:

$\rho(l) = \dfrac{\gamma(t + l, t)}{\sqrt{\gamma(t+l, t+l)\,\gamma(t,t)}} = \dfrac{\gamma(l)}{\gamma(0)}$

The numerator equality is fine, as it complies with book conventions for stationary series:

$\gamma(t + l, t) = \gamma(l, 0) = \gamma(l)$

As probably suggested by A.M. in his comment, it is the denominator that causes trouble; cause for it to hold we would need that:

$\gamma(t+l, t+l) = \gamma(t, t)$

as $\gamma(t,t)$ does follow the pattern of $\gamma(t+h, t) = \gamma(h, 0) = \gamma(h)$; hence could be abbreviated as $\gamma(t+0, t) = \gamma(0, 0) = \gamma(0)$, for our stationary series. But $\gamma(t+l, t+l)$ does not follow same pattern, hence not sure we can assume above equality to hold. Now, I am having trouble calling this a typo in book cause there may be exercises which seem to depend on it (eg see related exercise 1.10b).

I still struggle then, what I am missing here?

Comment: "$\gamma(0)$" makes no sense unless the series is stationary, which is impossible when $|A|\ne 1.$  You need to apply a more general definition of correlation.

Comment: Follow the definition of ACF (1.15 p18) and use that to solve the problem.

Comment: The denominator $\gamma(0)$ needs to be corrected and replaced by $\sqrt{\gamma(x_t,x_t)\gamma(x_{t+l},x_{t+l})}$